# Is it possible to inject react context to div outside the root in react (under the body)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cytoscape.js, react-context, popper.js

I am working with react cytoscape library. Try to integrate to popper plugin of cytoscape. 
the popper "content" property expect to return a div element describe the popper which appended to the "body" element. 
Since the context provider is under the root element , that div can't be consumer of that context. 
How can I use the same context also in the popper element which define outside the root.

Working with react component for cytoscape but the plugins of cytoscape are in pure js.

```
<body>
 <div id=root>
  <Style_Provider>
      .
      .
      .
  </Style_Provider>
 </div>
 <div id="popper">
    // need to access to style context
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The popper enforce me to append it to the "Body".
so, do u have any idea how can I access the style context under that restriction

Comment: not sure, but might want to look into portals in react

Comment: @EricHasselbring - Portals **exactly** address this, nice one!

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?  I'm having trouble integrating the Popper plugin with react-cytoscape.  Specifically, Cytoscape.use(Popper) throws an error saying target is undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Eric Hasselbring said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57477604/is-it-possible-to-inject-react-context-to-div-outside-the-root-in-react-under-t?noredirect=1#comment101428379_57477604), [portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) address this use case:

> Portals provide a first-class way to render children into a DOM node that exists outside the DOM hierarchy of the parent component.

Here's an example, using context:

```js
const ExampleContext = React.createContext(
    "default context"
);

class Example extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ExampleContext.Provider value="context from Example">
              <div>
                  This is the parent comnponent.
                  <MyPortal />
              </div>
            </ExampleContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}

class MyPortal extends React.Component {
    static contextType = ExampleContext;
    render() {
        return ReactDOM.createPortal(
            <div>This is "my portal," context stuff is "{this.context}"</div>,
            document.getElementById("portal")
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Example />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<hr>
<div id="portal"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

---

In a comment you said:

> the popper creates those 'divs' dynamically. Hence, I cant create 'MyPortal' component initially.

Just make the creation of the portal conditional. Here's the above, but with a button to show/hide the portal:

```js
const ExampleContext = React.createContext(
    "default context"
);

class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showPortal: false
        };
        this.showHideClick = this.showHideClick.bind(this);
    }

    showHideClick() {
        this.setState(({showPortal}) => ({showPortal: !showPortal}));
    }

    render() {
        const {showPortal} = this.state;
        return (
            <ExampleContext.Provider value="context from Example">
              <div>
                  This is the parent comnponent.
                  <input type="button" value={showPortal ? "Hide" : "Show"} onClick={this.showHideClick}/>
                  {showPortal && <MyPortal />}
              </div>
            </ExampleContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}

class MyPortal extends React.Component {
    static contextType = ExampleContext;
    render() {
        return ReactDOM.createPortal(
            <div>This is "my portal," context stuff is "{this.context}"</div>,
            document.getElementById("portal")
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Example />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<hr>
<div id="portal"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: the popper creates those 'divs' dynamically.
Hence, I cant create 'MyPortal' component initially.

Comment: @cryptoun - You don't have to. Just do it when it's appropriate. I've added an example of making it conditional above.